# the method render(String) in the type index is not applicable for the arguments in play 2.2.x

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0

Hi i am new in play framework for java i am following the this tutorial

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList

under the heading " Rendering the first page "

```
public static Result tasks() {
  return ok(
    views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm)
  );
}
```

i am using eclipse at the render line eclipse show me the error saying

the method render(String)  in the type index is not applicable for the arguments (List,Form)

as i am a beginner i am following this tutorial to learn play framework i don't know why is this error showing up 
please help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also confused like you when i saw compile error in eclipse.. :)

I just ignored eclipse compile error and refreshed the page. It worked even without package name before "Task" class.

I think eclipse can't understand it unless play compiler compiles "index.scala.html" with new changes.

So no worries, just refresh the page and you will see desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong arguments to your template. Your template accepts a String, and you're giving it a List and a Form.

If you go through [the tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList) more carefully, you'll see two things. First, in the **Overview** section, there's a paragraph about the general structure of templates:

> The first line defines the function signature. Here it takes a single String parameter. Then the template content mixes HTML (or any text-based language) with Scala statements. The Scala statements start with the special @ character.

Then, there's a section named **The application template** (and yes, that one comes before the code snippet you're quoting, which means you just went over it without reading it). There, the tutorial tells you to modify your `index.scala.html` template, and especially the first line to

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task])
```

Now your template can take a List and a Form.

Comment: i already did that as i am following the tutorial i already added this line to my index.scala.html  @(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[Task]) but still its giving me the error i am followig the tutorial as it was given

Comment: @sitwaheed9 Do you only get the error inside Eclipse or also when you open the page in a browser? If you run your app via `run` in the Play console, the templates are only recompiled if you load a page. Eclipse probably won't compile the templates, so there's only the old version until you load the page in a browser. You could try running your app with `~run`. Then, Play will recompile the template when you save it.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.scala.html you need to modify the Task with package name.Task. Also if eclipse shows a compilation error , the application will run fine .
Am using play 2.3 and once you run the application the compilation error will disappear from IDE

```
@(tasks: List[model.Task], taskForm: Form[model.Task])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {

<h1>@tasks.size() task(s)</h1>

<ul>
    @for(task <- tasks) {
        <li>
            @task.label

            @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<h2>Add a new task</h2>

@form(routes.Application.newTask()) {

    @inputText(taskForm("label")) 

    <input type="submit" value="Create">

}
```

}

where model is my Task class package